# VideoView not playing on some devices

Tags: android, mp4, android-videoview

I have fragment which contains CameraPreview as background and in one of the corners i have 100x100dp video view which must play mp4 h.264 format video,
but for some reason some of the devices play other won't the problem that no error thrown it just not showing .
This is the function to prepare the video.

```
private void setupVideoView(){
    String path = "android.resource://"+ getActivity().getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.model_2;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    mVideoView.seekTo(1);

    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });
}
```

then after couple seconds i need to start the video, then i call

```
if(mVideoView != null){
        mVideoView.start();
    }
```

i had read about which codecs and format android accept and my video is perfect suit this requirements as i said above its mp4 h.264 format , any idea?

Comment: i was the same problem, try to decode the video again https://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp4

Comment: and it helped you?

Comment: @PavelPoley i decoded but nothing changed :(

Comment: Do you get any Warnings or Errors in Logcat?

Comment: @KaranModi no any errors

Comment: UPDATE: after couple of hours i realized that the videoView is do playing but for some reason in beneath the CameraSourcePreview, all other views are above only the videoView isn't. How this can be fixed??

Comment: can you share your layout xml file?